# stored procedure return .00 decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

this stored procedure does not return salary with decimal format 00.00

```
ALTER PROCEDURE taxable_varsalary

@emp_code bigint,
@co_id bigint      

AS
declare @t_varsalary decimal(8,2)

set @t_varsalary  = (select sum(tran_value) from emp_ded_ben_trans where emp_code=@emp_code and co_id=@co_id and period_flg=2 and tax_flg=0)

RETURN @t_varsalary
```

Comment: return only works with int values.

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE taxable_varsalary

 @emp_code bigint,
 @co_id bigint,
 @t_varsalary decimal(8,2) OUTPUT

AS

   select @t_varsalary  = sum(tran_value) 
   from emp_ded_ben_trans 
   where emp_code=@emp_code and co_id=@co_id and period_flg=2 and tax_flg=0
```

The return value for a stored procedure has to be an `int`. Use an output parameter instead or `select` it

Comment: (or a data set with one row and one column)

Comment: I do agree, I didn't noticed that shmandor is returning some value. +1 for good catch

Comment: @smith -kelley said there no data put i am sure there are data returned from query

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried using the query in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

A stored procedure return only returns an `integer`, either use an OUTPUT parameter or do a SELECT at the end

Answer (score 1):

Create a *Scalar-Valued Function*:

```
CREATE FUNCTION taxable_varsalary
    @emp_code bigint,
    @co_id bigint
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
AS
declare @t_varsalary decimal(8,2)

set @t_varsalary  = (select sum(tran_value) from emp_ded_ben_trans where emp_code=@emp_code and co_id=@co_id and period_flg=2 and tax_flg=0)

RETURN @t_varsalary
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below with `OUTPUT`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE taxable_varsalary

@emp_code bigint,
@co_id bigint      

AS
BEGIN
declare @t_varsalary MONEY

set @t_varsalary  = (select sum(tran_value) from emp_ded_ben_trans where emp_code=@emp_code and co_id=@co_id and period_flg=2 and tax_flg=0)

SELECT @t_varsalary OUTPUT

END
```